Wrong output-regex
import re
import urllib3
url = 'https://bazaartracker.com/search?query=rough+ruby'
def extract_dynamic_numbers_from_url(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    content = response.data.decode('utf-8')

    pattern = r'<span class="text-subtle-100">([\d.]+)\s*coins<\/span>'
    dynamic_numbers = re.findall(pattern, content)

    return dynamic_numbers
print(extract_dynamic_numbers_from_url(url))

when I run it it print square brackets
I tried to change pattern multiple times to narrow it down but that resulted in square brackets or that it didn't find anything
Im using urllib3 to scrape the HTML into string in my code and then use regex to find something within it

Ever considered that the website could block scrapers ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use selenium and bs4.

Have you looked at the exact HTML you get back?  That pattern is only present inside a Javascript string.  The elements are all constructed on the fly using Javascript.  Regexes are, in general, a terrible way to deal with HTML.

Old adage:   I had a problem.  I decided to use a regular expression.  Now I have two problems.

You should never try to parse HTML with REGEX. It's not something one should do, ever..

@TimRoberts yes I read through the text it gives me and there's everything i need to extract from it

there is an api endpoint, use it instead

import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Origin': 'https://bazaartracker.com',
}

def get_prices(item):
    params = {
        'query': item,
    }

    response = requests.get('https://api.bazaartracker.com/search', params=params, headers=headers)

    item = response.json()[0]

    return {
        "name": item["item"]["name"],
        "buy": item["product"]["buyprice"],
        "sell": item["product"]["sellprice"],
    }

Example results.
print(get_prices("rough ruby"))
print(get_prices("enchanted carrot on a stick"))
print(get_prices("super compactor 3000"))

{'name': 'Rough Ruby Gem', 'buy': 2.3, 'sell': 1.2}
{'name': 'Enchanted Carrot on a Stick', 'buy': 47373.1666666666, 'sell': 5390.97647058823}
{'name': 'Super Compactor 3000', 'buy': 304646.47142857144, 'sell': 271344.9625}


thanks for feedback. Does this work only on mozilla or can i use other browsers?

This doesn't use Mozilla or any other browser. It's a simple Python script that accesses the API behind the site to get the data. Have you tried running the script?
